# Weld Ambiguous dependency with @Alternative

Tags: java, cdi, weld

I have an injection point in one of my classes

```
@Inject
private UsbServices usbServices;
```

And a Weld class with the `@Produces` method

```
public class AppProducer
{

    @Produces
    @Singleton
    public UsbServices getUsbServices()
    {
        UsbServices usbServices = null;
        try
        {
            usbServices = UsbHostManager.getUsbServices();
        } catch (SecurityException | UsbException e)
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return usbServices;
    }

}
```

I wish to swap in alternative implementation during integration testing, so I have an alternative version of the above class

```
@Alternative
public class TestAppProducer
{

    @Produces
    @Singleton
    public UsbServices getUsbServices()
    {
        return new UsbServicesSimulator();
    }

}
```

As well as the following in my beans.xml inside the test package resources/META-INF

```
<beans xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
      http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/beans_1_0.xsd">
      <alternatives>
          <class>xxx.TestAppProducer</class>
      </alternatives>
</beans>
```

To test this I'm trying to kick off Weld with it's main class and manually attach a USB 'device'. The test method has the following

```
Weld weld = new Weld();
WeldContainer container = weld.initialize();
PCSyncApplication app = container.instance().select(PCSyncApplication.class).get();
ServicesManager servMan = app.getServicesManager();
UsbServicesSimulator servSimulator = (UsbServicesSimulator) servMan.getUsbServices();
servSimualtor.attachDevice(new FakeDevice());
```

But I'm getting a ambiguous dependency exception

```
Exception in thread "main" org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DeploymentException: Exception List with 2 exceptions:
Exception 0 :
org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DeploymentException: WELD-001409: Ambiguous dependencies for type UsbServices with qualifiers @Default
  at injection point [BackedAnnotatedField] @Inject private xxx.manager.ServicesManager.usbServices
  at xxx.manager.ServicesManager.usbServices(ServicesManager.java:0)
  Possible dependencies: 
  - Managed Bean [class xxx.simulator.usb.UsbServicesSimulator] with qualifiers [@Any @Default],
  - Producer Method [UsbServices] with qualifiers [@Any @Default] declared as [[BackedAnnotatedMethod] @Produces @Singleton public xxx.AppProducer.getUsbServices()]
```

EDIT: Small update if I annotate the `UsbServicesSimulator` with the following the message goes away

```
@Alternative
public class UsbServicesSimulator implements UsbServices
```

But I'm not entirely sure I understand why. I would've thought the `TestAppProducer` and the `<alternatives>` section of `beans.xml` would be enough?

Comment: Actually your error indicates that `UsbServices` is already a managed bean.  You should `@Veto` it so that it doesn't generate any bean definitions by itself.

Comment: The implementation of `UsbServices` provided by `UsbHostManager.getUsbServices()` is a third party class so I can't annotate it

Comment: What container (including version) are you working against?

Comment: I'm using Weld Java SE 2.3.0.Final

Answer (score 1):

With @Alternative annotation you could only disable you Test service, but not resolve ambiguous dependency. If you want to enable you Alternative, the main version should not be visible in class path or should have the lower priority, e.x. @Priority annotated or disabled with beans.xml or @Vetoed. 
There are also some other techniques,
you can find the full documentation here https://docs.jboss.org/weld/reference/latest/en-US/html/injection.html#alternatives

I prefer to use separate projects, or run the Test with Arquillian and have in class path only that class, what I need.
I would not recommend to use priorities in that case. Because you will need to disable or set lower priority for you Production version.